# My claimed clash mob prize didn't appear in my inventory

Tags: ios, infinity-blade-2

I didn't receive my clash mob prize after winning. It was in the victory section and I pressed claim reward, but it's not in my inventory. The things I am missing are a ring and a big prize wheel.

Answer (score -1):

That sounds like a glitch. I had same thing happen to me, but I didn't care that much to pursue the reason.

If you absolutely need that item you can try messaging support. Otherwise there is no other way to get items back.